# How to delete or yank inside slashes and asterisks?

Tags: vim

I use `di"` for quotes `di{` for brackets and `dit` for HTML tags.

I often work with CSS. I want to delete inside slashes or asterisks. For example:

```
/* This is a comment. Delete or yank me. ;) */
.button {
  content: 'Change my comment.';
}
```

I dont want to do it with functions etc. How I map these keywords with all variations? (Specially I need to `delete inside`, `yank inside`, `delete around`, `delete and go insert mode (ci/)` ) Like:

```
di/
yi/
ci/
ya/
da/
di*
ya*
```

etc...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define your own text-objects by combining a visual mode mapping and an operator-pending mode mapping.

This snippet will create a `i/` text-object:

```
xnoremap i/ :<C-u>normal! T/vt/<CR>
onoremap i/ :normal vi/<CR>
```

that you can use like the built-in ones: `ci/`, `vi/`, `di/`, `yi/`.

And this one will create a `a/` text-object:

```
xnoremap a/ :<C-u>normal! F/vf/<CR>
onoremap a/ :normal va/<CR>
```

that you can use like the built-in ones: `ca/`, `va/`, `da/`, `ya/`.

---

BONUS: here is an easily expandable snippet from my `vimrc` that creates no less than **26** new text-objects, including the ones you want:

```
for char in [ '_', '.', ':', ',', ';', '<bar>', '/', '<bslash>', '*', '+', '%', '-', '#' ]
    execute 'xnoremap i' . char . ' :<C-u>normal! T' . char . 'vt' . char . '<CR>'
    execute 'onoremap i' . char . ' :normal vi' . char . '<CR>'
    execute 'xnoremap a' . char . ' :<C-u>normal! F' . char . 'vf' . char . '<CR>'
    execute 'onoremap a' . char . ' :normal va' . char . '<CR>'
endfor
```

Comment: Wow! Your snippet is amazing. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 6):

There is also the excellent [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) plugin which includes those text objects plus a huge number of others as well. Could be worth checking out, especially if you don't want to have to define your own.